# Add offset values to the dates and check if they fall in min max range

Tags: sas

Below i have date data am trying to code to see if new RFDTC column values fall in the respective range, i.e if min=1 & max=20 then all the column observations from RFDTC column should be added by the same random value which is calculated as below--->

```
if min < max then min+(max-min) 
else max > min then max+(min - max)
```

help is appreciated how can i code this in datastep to get new dates after adding the value between min and max...?

input data-->

```
RFDTC
1975-12-04
1977-11-03
1989-09-15
1998-06-17
1999-05-31
2000-08-14
2001-03-11
2007-03-11
2007-12-28
2008-10-07
2009-12-03
2012-10-16
2014-06-15

%let min=1;
%let max=20;
data want;
set RFDTC;
where
```

Comment: RFDTC is a date variable, adding it isn't going to produce a meaningful result. You should post an example of the input dataset that you have and the output dataset that you want and the code you've tried so far.

Comment: Also check your desired if/else expression. Both are min < max.